# How much of my teaching evaluations to bring to an interview?

Tags: teaching, interview

I'm interviewing for a lecturership (purely teaching, maybe 10% research).  I've taught one course before and I have received a thorough (positive) evaluation from my students.  However, my institution feels that more information is better, so my evaluation is 28 pages long.  Do I bring the whole thing, one copy per interview committee member, or would just the summary section (where the main numerical results are) be enough?

Comment: Is there any reason not to bring several copies? It seems like a situation where it is better to bring too much than too little.

Comment: Perhaps? I'm thinking that handing each member of the committe a huge pile of papers, including things like assignments/other work, might be a bit much?

Comment: Have they specifically asked you to bring evaluations to the interview? If not, I see no reason to bring them at all.  Just in case, you may want to have an electronic copy, which you could send to them if they want to see it.  In this day and age, I doubt that anybody really wants to have it on paper.

Comment: @Thomas Limiting paper waste...?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not really sure.  I believe I was just told to bring any materials I feel will help the hiring committee make a decision

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky I would assume, unless specifically told otherwise, that "bring any materials" means "make sure any materials are on the laptop you're bringing with you".

Answer (score 3):

Teaching evals are super important to lecturer search committees.  But nobody wants paper.  Email it to the search committee or upload it to their application site.